# How to handle dynamic data type for object of models in angular

Tags: angular, dynamic, model, typeclass, complex-data-types

I have some models that I use it as data types, and I have to choose one of them depends on some conditions.
Currently I'm using if conditions, but I'm looking for dynamic way if it possible.

`

handleWizardContext(wizardContextModel: WizardContextModel):BookNewJobStrategyDto | CancelJobStrategyDto {

```
    let context: BookNewJobStrategyDto | CancelJobStrategyDto;
    if (wizardContextModel.wizardId === Wizards.BookNewJob) {  // handle context of book new job
        context = new BookNewJobStrategyDto();
    }
    else if (wizardContextModel.wizardId === Wizards.CancelJob) { // handle context of cancel job
        context = new CancelJobStrategyDto();
        context.wizardId = wizardContextModel.wizardId;
        context.projectId = wizardContextModel.projectId;
        context.jobVisitId = wizardContextModel.jobVisit.jobVisitId;
        context.jobId = wizardContextModel.jobVisit.jobId;
        context.projectRegionId = wizardContextModel.jobVisit.projectRegionId;
        context.siteId = wizardContextModel.jobVisit.siteId;
    } else {
        context = ((new Object()) as any);
    }
    // there will be more else if conditions here
    return context;
}`
```

[the selected method should handle 13 case, so I need to get dynamic way to do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVMq1.png)

Comment: Please share the code in a way that we can copy it for an answer.

Comment: I edited the question